# Using '<=' operator in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Can any one explain me the reason why this particular module doesn'twork when we use '<=' instead of '='

```
module TestCell(x0, x1, y0, y1, z);
input x0, x1, y0, y1;
output z;
reg z;
reg a1, a2, a3, a4;
always @(x0 or x1 or y0 or y1) begin
a1 <= ~(x0 & y1);
a2 <= ~(y0 & x1);
a3 <= ~(a2 | a1);
a4 <= a2 & a1;
z <= ~(a4 | a3);
end
endmodule
```

And what we should ensure in order to use '<=' in verilog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cthulhu has said  `=` is blocking, That implies the statement will be evaluated before moving on to the next line of code.

```
always @* begin 
  a = b & c;
  d = e & f;
  g = a & d ;
end
```

The above example is the same as :

```
always @* begin
  g = b & c & e & f;
end
```

However if we switch to using `<=` Then they are no longer the same in simulation, the g will be the OLD a AND OLD b. Since this is a combinatorial block, ie not regularly triggered or evaluated like a flip-flop, you will get odd results from simulation.

Correct use of the `<=` non-blocking assignment is in implying flip-flop.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (!rst_n) begin
    a <= 1'b0;
    d <= 1'b0;
    g <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
      a <= b & c;
      d <= e & f;
      g <= a & d ;
  end
end
```

In the Flip-Flop example above g takes the value of a and d from last clk cycle not the current evaluation.

In your example you have used `always @(sensitivity list)`, that is a combinatorial circuit and `=` would be the correct usage. I would also recommend switching to `always @*` if your simulator allows it. The `*` is a wildcard and removes the need for manually entering the sensitivity list.

I think that is is worth remembering that synthesis tools will base their results on the statement following the `always @` If it is edge based they will use a type of flip-flop if it is combinatorial they will place combinatorial logic. The use of `=` or `<=` only has an effect in simulation. Using the wrong type means your simulation will not match the synthesised hardware.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the case of combinational logic there is `"="` for assignment, and for the sequential block we have the `"<="` operator.
2. `"="` is blocking assignment and `"<="` is nonblocking assignment.
3. `"="` executes code sequentially inside a begin / end, whereas nonblocking `"<="` executes in parallel.

**[More](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day3.html)**

Comment: Can you give me example where "<=" is used in verilog. Actually I want to implement pipelined version of aes encryption.

Comment: Did you see the [**More**](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day3.html) link in the answer?

Comment: You are using creating a combinatorial circuit above do not use `<=`